Setting the source of an image through javascript is not working
I'm using firebase storage to store some images, however, when I want to set the source of an <img> element to the corresponding URL, it just works on some images. This is the function I'm trying to implement:
function setImgUrl (element, imgPath) {
    getDownloadURL(refStorage(storage, imgPath))
    .then((url) => {
        element.src = url;
    })
}

I've found through the debugger that both the element and the image url are getting correctly passed to the .then(), but when it tries to set the source it just doesn't work. I've tried both with element.src = url and element.setAttribute('src', url), but the result is the same. The images on which it doesn't work seem to be random even though when I reload the page they are the same.
After the code runs, the img looks like this:

I've also tried disabling the cache in the developers tools but it doesn't help.
Here I include a snippet to show how it works, even though I would rather not to show the real call to the database for security reasons. This should't be important, as the url and the element are correct when element.src = url is executed.


const URLs = ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/i-menu-73648.appspot.com/o/menu%2Fdubcl%2Fcarne_mechada.webp?alt=media&token=104e3285-f206-4fc1-a60b-db46dc3a8819", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/i-menu-73648.appspot.com/o/menu%2Fdubcl%2Fensalada_cesar.jpg?alt=media&token=b8d7a628-64b5-485d-8e63-c87411c9e564", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/i-menu-73648.appspot.com/o/menu%2Fdubcl%2Fensalada_de_pasta.jpg?alt=media&token=69eb5f17-befc-48e9-acfb-567f0a796082"]

function setImgURL(element, path) {
  const url = URLs[path]
  element.src = url
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  setImgURL(document.getElementById(`id-${i}`), i - 1)
}
<img id="id-1">
<img id="id-2">
<img id="id-3">




After the code runs, when you look at the <img> element with the DOM inspector, what do you see?

Please edit your question to include a URL that does work, and one that doesn't.

Welcome to StackOverflow! That may be a caching problem. Try Hezy Zivs answer to find out. You could also just deactivate caching in the developer tools of your browser to check if that's the problem. If that doesn't help, you should provide more information to get help here.

There needs to be enough information in your question that anyone can use the reproduce the issue.   The big problem I see is that we can't see what element is, so we don't know if you actually have the right value there.  Try reducing your code to just the minimal HTML and JavaScript required to run this code, so that makes it 100% clear that there can be no mistake in the values you show.  Please edit the question to show this.

try to add a random string to the image that will force it to reload
const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
      element.src = url + `?v=${randomString}`;


When I run it with the string it happens the same, the link gets correctly passed to the function and it works, but when it tries to set the source anything happens.
